# Inscribed right triangle in a rectangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, rectangles

[Image with another angles][1]There is a rectangle with sides of 24 and 25 centimeters. In it, there is a triangle with sides of unknown length. I need to find out the length of $x$.

[![diagram][2]][2]

Comment: please show what you have tried

Comment: I found out, that triangles AED, EBF and FCD are similar because their angles are the same - 90°, alpha-90 and alpha in all three triangles

Comment: $\frac {\overline {FB}}{\overline {EB}} = \frac {\overline {CF}}{\overline {CD}} = \frac {\overline {AD}}{\overline {AE}}$  and $\overline {FB} +\overline {CB} = \overline {AD} = 25$ and $\overline {AE} + \overline {EB} = \overline {CD} = 24$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track - finding similar triangles could be the first step into solving the problem.

By similar triangles, we know the ratio of the sides will be the same. Hence, trigonometry will be useful here, as this is one way we can relate angles to the ratio of the sides. You have $3$ similar triangles in the diagram.

Now some good Algebra can come to your aid.

Here are some useful hints that might help you:

- How can $FB$ be expressed in terms of $x$?
- How can $EB$ be expressed in terms of $AE$?

Comment: This looks like a question in some mathematics competition? Or am I wrong and id is just homework?